# NTFS drive is not mounted after changing /etc/fstab

Tags: macos, ntfs

I edited the fstab file in order to enable writing on ntfs drives and added all three of my external ntfs drives to it. Two of them work fine.

The third one which I added by **label** because it did not have a uuid, however, is not mounted after editing.
I am on El Capitan by the way.

Comment: Why did you need to edit fstab?  Doesn't ntfs drives mount automatically? Do the drives show up when entering `diskutil  list` in a Terminal application window? Are these drives internal or external?

Comment: I wanted to enable writing on ntfs drives. All of them are external drives and they all show up but one is not mounted. I tried to mount it with the mount command with write permission but it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of that volume and it worked.

Comment: This actually worked for me. Why down-voted?

Answer (score 3):

Generally the mount command is not used under the OS X operating system. Apple has there own command called diskutil. This basically the command line version of the Disk Utility application. The command line version has more functionality than the UI version. If an external drive is recognized by OS X, it will show up under `diskutil list` as `/dev/diskX` were `X` is a positive integer. To mount a drive enter the following command.

```
diskutil mountDisk /dev/diskX
```

To unmount use the following.

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX
```

Partition `Y` on disk `X` is denoted as `/dev/disk/XsY` as shown in `diskutil list`. To mount and unmount a partition use the following.

```
diskutil mount /dev/diskXsY
diskutil unmount /dev/diskXsY
```

The `mount` command can used to see if a partition is currently mounted. Just enter the command without any options.

Be default NTFS partitions are mounted as read only. I guess there is a way to mount without the protection of read only status, but from what I have read this is unsafe.

Companies such as [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) offer software that allows OS X to write to NTFS volumes. I have never used such software.

Comment: The software you mentioned are not free, mostly.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the **LABEL** and **UUID**?
Because I used LABEL for this one and UUID for the other two.

Comment: @ssd352: Why did not you try using a UUID for all three? I did test a MBR partitioned, FAT formatted flash drive and both LABEL and UUID options work for read only mounting.

Comment: I mentioned the reason in the question.

Comment: @ssd352: What do you mean when you say there is no UUID. If you plug the disk into the Mac and run the command `diskutil  list`, does not the drive show up? If it does, then use the IDENTIFIER to enter the command `diskutil  info  IDENTIFIER`. The output should show a value for the Volume UUID. For example, my flash drive has the IDENTIFIER of `/dev/disk1s1` so the command would be `diskutil  info  /dev/disk1s1`.

Comment: @ssd352: Another question: does your label have any space characters? If so, each space character has to be replaced with `\040` in the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: I mean when I use diskutil info ID, no UUID shows up. Everything else is there.

I knew about spaces but it doesn't have any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I was using mounty and after head aches for couple weeks I found this forum and like The “ssd352” I changed the volume name and right now working fine on High Sierra.

I edited the /etc/fstab and added UUID= instead LABEL=
Like this UUID= (search it over terminal diskutil info /dev/disk or diskutil volume name) nome ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse